# Fluid 960 Accordion Expansion

Tags: css, accordion, fluid, 960.gs

I'm revamping a site using http://www.designinfluences.com/fluid960gs/

Fluid 960 uses uses MooTools as well as some other techniques.

How do I cause an accordion submenu item other than the first one to render expanded when loading a page that implements the Fluid 960 Accordion style?  I tried the "current" and "selected" classes on the `<li>` and `<a>` tags, but they don't work.

I also noticed on the reference page for the fluid CSS their Menu Accordion has an "active" class on the Submenu 3 that doesn't seem to do anything.

Gonna work on a small example piece of code now, but am hoping someone can answer w/o it.

Comment: You're assuming everybody knows what this script(?) is. Link to it. The top results for that phrase are um...a bunch of forum threads asking about it.

Comment: Added the link to the 960 fluid template I'm following

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was misunderstanding the 960 Fluid templates and how they implemented the accordion.  In the end I modified the .js code that created the accordion and passed a javascript variable to the FX.accordion creation code so the show:myNewVar parameter get's set and the accordion renders with the correct item expanded.

Additionally: I wanted to stop the accordion from "expanding" during rendering so I used the show:X param instead of the display:X param which would have preserved the initial animated accordion opening and made the correct section render.